# Can't find missing packages Oracle Linux 8

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-18c

super newbie here. Trying to learn DBA stuff.

I've been trying to install oracle database 18c on Oracle Linux 8 but there are two missing packages that are just not being found. I need these to complete the installation properly:

```
 nothing provides compat-libcap1 needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
- nothing provides compat-libstdc++-33 needed by oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
```

These two commands do not work.

rpm -ivh compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.x86_64.rpm

rpm -ivh compat-libcap1-1.10-7.el7.x86_64.rpm

I've looked a lot online.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to install the "oracle-database-preinstall-18c" package, using the "yum" utility as root. That will load all of your dependencies for you:

```
[root@orcl1 ~]# yum search oracle-database-preinstall-18c
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
================================================================== N/S matched: oracle-database-preinstall-18c ===================================================================
oracle-database-preinstall-18c.x86_64 : Sets the system for Oracle Database single instance and Real Application Cluster install for Oracle Linux 7

[root@orcl1 ~]# yum install oracle-database-preinstall-18c
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package oracle-database-preinstall-18c.x86_64 0:1.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: compat-libstdc++-33 for package: oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64 0:3.2.3-72.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                   Arch                              Version                                  Repository                             Size
==================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 oracle-database-preinstall-18c                            x86_64                            1.0-1.el7                                ol7_latest                             18 k
Installing for dependencies:
 compat-libstdc++-33                                       x86_64                            3.2.3-72.el7                             ol7_latest                            190 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 208 k
Installed size: 866 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

It should be noted that Oracle 18c isn't supported on Oracle Linux 8; ideally you should be using Oracle Linux 7. See these articles for install steps and guidelines:

- [Database Installation Guide for Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0)
- [Oracle Database 18c Installation On Oracle Linux 8 (OL8)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/oracle-db-18c-installation-on-oracle-linux-8)

Comment: With Oracle 19c on RHEL 8.4, I was able solve the same problem by "yum localinstall" the CentOS 7 packages after grabbing them with: wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/compat-libcap1-1.10-7.el7.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Technically that's a work-around hack, not a supported solution, even if it appears to work. Oracle doesn't support 18c on OL8 or RHEL8. Working with/developing on unsupported configurations is unwise on a number of levels, especially for a newbie.

Comment: According to Oracle, RHEL 8 *is* supported by Oracle 19c (see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/supported-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8-distributions-for-x86-64.html), but these packages aren't listed in the required packages list (although "libstdc++" is).  I think the optional RHEL 7 repos do have these libraries in them, but I couldn't find them in the option RHEL 8 repos (partly because there are so many of them now)!

Comment: The question was specific to 18c, not 19c. 18c is not supported.

Comment: This is true and why I prefaced my original comment "With Oracle 19c ... solve the same problem..."  I wanted to leave information for someone who was having a similar problem with Oracle 19c since this answer was useful in that case as well.  (I'm just trying to be helpful, but I can remove my comments if you feel that they are unuseful to others who have the same problem as I did.)

Answer (score 1):

18c is not supported on OL8.

The `oracle-database-preinstall-18c` package does not exist in the  OL8 repository.

`compat-libcap1` and `compat-libstdc++-33` packages also do not exist in OL8 repository.

Whatever instructions you followed to get here were not completely correct.

Use OL6 or OL7 for 18c.

You said you were a super newbie, you should start with stuff that works as expected.

[Oracle Database 18c Installation On Oracle Linux 6 (OL6) and 7 (OL7)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/oracle-db-18c-installation-on-oracle-linux-6-and-7)